# How to convert w command idle timeout in seconds?

Tags: bash, shell

I am trying to use below command to find out the idle time of a user but the idle time is being displayed in all the formats like seconds, hour or days. How can I change it display all the time only in seconds.

```
w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5 | tail -n+3
```

Result

```
testuser 10days
ec2-user 3.00s
```

Is there a way I can display 10 days in seconds?
I see one link [here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/191436/linux-w-command-get-idle-time-in-seconds) with the answer but that uses epoch time whihc I don't wanna use.

Comment: If the time ends in `days`, multiply the number by `86400`.

Comment: If it's like `2:32m`, split it at the `:`, multiply the first number by `60` and add the second number. If it's like `21:34`, it's `21*3600 + 34*60`.

Comment: The beautiful thing about epoch time is that it's trivial to convert to any other form. Even if you don't want it as your output, it's perfect for use as an intermediate form.

Comment: @Barmar I wanted to avoid doing that and instead if there is command which I can use?

Comment: "wanted to avoid doing that" **why**? Bash 4.3 and newer can even do the conversion from epoch time to other formats built into the shell itself, avoiding the need for `date` or any other external tools.

Comment: [so] is for programming questions, so we assume you're interested in writing a script to process the output.

Comment: The question you linked to has this in the first answer: **If you want the age instead of the absolute time, post-process it to subtract it from the current time** and then shows how to do this.

Comment: I understand that and looks like splitting is the only way I can solve this. Thanks for confirming.

Comment: The second answer shows how to do all the splitting and multiplication, although the multiplier for days is wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a bash solution:

```bash
WishSeconds () {

    # PARM 1: 'w' command idle time 44.00s, 5:10, 1:28m, 3days, etc.
    #      2: Variable name (no $ is used) to receive idel time in seconds

    # NOTE: Idle time resets to zero when user types something in terminal.
    #       A looping job calling a command doesn't reset idle time.

    local Wish Unit1 Unit2
    Wish="$1"
    declare -n Seconds=$2

    # Leading 0 is considered octal value in bash. Change ':09' to ':9'
    Wish="${Wish/:0/:}"

    if [[ "$Wish" == *"days"* ]] ; then
        Unit1="${Wish%%days*}"
        Seconds=$(( Unit1 * 86400 ))
    elif [[ "$Wish" == *"m"* ]] ; then
        Unit1="${Wish%%m*}"
        Unit2="${Unit1##*:}"
        Unit1="${Unit1%%:*}"
        Seconds=$(( (Unit1 * 3600) + (Unit2 * 60) ))
    elif [[ "$Wish" == *"s"* ]] ; then
        Seconds="${Wish%%.*}"
    else
        Unit1="${Wish%%:*}"
        Unit2="${Wish##*:}"
        Seconds=$(( (Unit1 * 60) + Unit2 ))
    fi

} # WishSeconds

WishSeconds "20days" Days ; echo Passing 20days: $Days
WishSeconds "1:10m"  Hours ; echo Passing 1:10m: $Hours
WishSeconds "1:30"   Mins ; echo Passing 1:30: $Mins
WishSeconds "44.20s" Secs ; echo Passing 44.20s: $Secs
```

### Results

```bash
Passing 20days: 1728000
Passing 1:10m: 4200
Passing 1:30: 90
Passing 44.20s: 44
```

### Note

Instead of using:

```bash
w | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5 | tail -n+3
```

You can chop off the tail and use:

```bash
w -h | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5
```

This will remove the headers for you. I do the same plus use short format (sans CPU stats) and IP addresses instead of host names so I use:

```bash
w -ish | tr -s " " | cut -d" " -f1,5
```

Use `man w` for more argument details.